# How Do I Type with IPA (International Phonetic Alphabet)?

Tags: keyboard

How Do I Type with IPA (International Phonetic Alphabet)? I need to type in Phonetics, but I cannot find a keyboard. I tried the IPA Unicode 6.2 keyboard, but it did not work. It installed, but when I selected it, I could only type the normal english-latin characters. I cannot use copy/paste sites like [This](http://ipa.typeit.org/), as I need to type a lot.

I am using a MacBook Pro, With Sierra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the [standard IPA layout](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ipa-sil_keyboard) doesn't work for you, I would suggest making a custom keyboard layout with [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=ukelele) (or if you prefer text-based editing, [KeyLayoutMaker](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=keylayoutmaker)).

Alternatively, if you don't need quite the level of speed that can offer, you can simply use the Character Palette (Edit > Emoji and Symbols) to type the characters by double-clicking them. To get the "Phonetic Alphabet" pane to show up, customize which are visible with the gear icon in the top left.

[image: character palette]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really helped me. I was frustrated typing through the emoji symbols.

Answer (score 2):

You should normally not have a problem making the IPA keyboard work. It uses "dead keys" to create the IPA characters. A “dead key” is a key that does not generate a character, but rather changes the character generated by a following keystroke. For example, in the IPA keyboard, to get the “ə”,you would type the dead key “=” followed by the “e” (=e).  Charts showing the how all the IPA characters are made this way can be found in [this PDF](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/render_download.php?format=file&media_id=IPAMSKLC1.4.pdf&filename=IPAMSKLC1.4.pdf).

[image]

Comment: Tried it. not working, anyway, can you explain how these deadkeys work in your answer?

Comment: It sure works ok for me.  What happens when you type the sequence =w =e =r =t =y =u =i =o =p ?  Do you not get ʍəɹθʏɯɪɒʘ ?  What app are you using?